# ROS-i ABB driver - publish more than 6 variable through /joint_states

Tags: ros, communication, ros-industrial, abb, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am basically trying to send the translational and rotational positions of the tip (total 7 float variables) from RAPID to the ROS as a ros topic. I was thinking of using the /joint_states topic's velocity and acceleration vectors to contain these variables. The end result that I expect will be the /joint_states topic publishing the 6 out of 7 variables as a position vector element and the last variable as first element in velocity.

However, I cannot seem to send more than 6 variable (I tried to pack more raw data beyond 6) using the send_msg function in the ros-i abb's socket module and the ROS_StateServer module. Has anyone done this before? or is there any proper way or guide of publishing to ros from rapid?

Thank you in advance!

---

Edit: Hi gvdhoorn! Thank you so much for the quick, detailed and amazing reply!

Due to the time constraint, I went ahead with the measure 2 and I finally got it working! The issue was indeed the mapping from the ros pc side (industrial_robot_client).

However, the changes in `controller_joint_names` parameter did not work for me (for all robot models). Instead, I went to hard code the `joint_names` variable of  `abb_robot_state_node.cpp` file in `abb_driver/src` and it worked out fine for me.

```
//initial configuration
//  std::vector<std::string> joint_names = rsi.get_joint_names();

//changed configuration
std::vector<std::string> joint_names;
joint_names.push_back("trans_x");
joint_names.push_back("trans_y");
joint_names.push_back("trans_z");
joint_names.push_back("rot_q1");
joint_names.push_back("rot_q2");
joint_names.push_back("rot_q3");
joint_names.push_back("rot_q4");
```

Oh by the way, if it does not cause too much trouble for you, could you please tell me where I can do the

> and finally extend the robot_state node to publish a ROS geometry_msgs/Pose (or perhaps a TF frame directly)

of the measure 1?
This is so that I can change the name of rostopic and also cater for other type of messages. I could not find any function or variable that looks like it.

Again Thank you very much!
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254243/ros-i-abb-driver---publish-more-than-6-variable-through-/joint_states/) by [ninanona](https://answers.ros.org/users/28699/ninanona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-10**:
A comment: please don't use screenshots to show us what is essentially text (the console output). Just copy-paste the text and use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) to properly format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am basically trying to send the translational and rotational positions of the tip (total 7 float variables) from RAPID to the ROS as a ros topic

So if I understand you correctly, you are looking for a way to transmit the Cartesian pose of the TCP to the `industrial_robot_client` nodes?

And then in XYZ+Quaternion form, correct?

> I was thinking of using the /joint_states topic's velocity and acceleration vectors to contain these variables

If possible, I would recommend *not* to do that: you'd be completely changing the semantics of the messages involved, which is really not a good idea (see also *note 6* under `JOINT_POSITION` in the specification document linked below).

You have two options:

1. define a new message (`TCP_POSE` or something similar) at the `simple_message` level, extend the RAPID code to send the required bytes (in the correct order) over the TCP socket, extend the `simple_message` package to include deserialisers for the `TCP_POSE` message and finally extend the `robot_state` node to publish a ROS `geometry_msgs/Pose` (or perhaps a TF frame directly). This would be the *recommended* approach.
2. abuse the `JOINT_POSITION` message: instead of sending joint space poses, insert your data into the `joint_data` array, leave `simple_message` and `robot_state` as they are and interprete ROS `JointState` messages on your own. Note that doing it this way would mean that you cannot reuse the ROS `robot_state_publisher`, as it will expect joint space poses.

> However, I cannot seem to send more than 6 variable (I tried to pack more raw data beyond 6) using the send_msg function in the ros-i abb's socket module and the ROS_StateServer module.

This suggests you went with option 2. This is definitely possible, but you need to take the layout of the messages into account: `JOINT_POSITION` messages contain a sequence nr (unused) and an array of 10 floats (see [Message Structures of the ROS-Industrial Simple Message Protocol - Message Definitions - JOINT_POSITION](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/rep-ros-i/blob/5e590aef43745c0035a2842d98d99b69dd35a631/rep-ixxxx.rst#joint-position)). The `abb_driver` RAPID code fills the first 6 elements of the `joint_data` array with the joint poses of the first 6 axes of the robot. The 4 other elements are set to 0.

On the ROS side, the entire message is deserialised (so all 10 elements from `joint_data`), but only the indices for which the `robot_status` node has a known mapping will be included in the `JointState` msgs it publishes. That mapping is defined in the `controller_joint_names` parameter ([here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/blob/2070af60a69c52c963d38678e5d798d3cf13f645/abb_irb2400_support/config/joint_names_irb2400.yaml) for an IRB 2400).

So in your specific case -- and for option 2 -- you'll have to change that parameter to include a seventh 'joint' (here you see the semantic problem).

If I have everything correct, that should lead to the `robot_state` node publishing all 7 values in the `position` array (which at this point are not the regular joint space poses but the XYZ+Quaternion TCP pose).

Note that there is no inherent limit in the length of the arrays/lists of a ROS `JointState` message: the only reason there are just 6 values there is because of the `controller_joint_names` parameter.

---

Edit:

> Due to the time constraint, I went ahead with the measure 2

Ah ..

> However, the changes in `controller_joint_names` parameter did not work for me (for all robot models). Instead, I went to hard code the `joint_names` variable of  `abb_robot_state_node.cpp` file in `abb_driver/src` and it worked out fine for me.

I probably won't have to tell you that hard-coding like that is also *really* not a good idea.

(I was going to suggest to try and diagnose what is going on with the parameter, but you shouldn't be doing this anyway, so let's not spend any effort in that direction)

> Oh by the way, if it does not cause too much trouble for you, could you please tell me where I can do the
>
> > and finally extend the robot_state node to publish a ROS geometry_msgs/Pose (or perhaps a TF frame directly)
>
> of the measure 1? This is so that I can change the name of rostopic and also cater for other type of messages. I could not find any function or variable that looks like it.

This is again something that should make your 'spidey sense' go off: you'll have to change the [joint_relay_handler.cpp](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core/blob/98b076fca4bf6f74a2d8c3f197fb608afea68d9f/industrial_robot_client/src/joint_relay_handler.cpp) in the `industrial_robot_client` package. In that file, the mapping between `simple_message` msgs and ROS msgs is done.

If you are going to do this, it would be really nice if you could take the next step (which is relatively small) and add that new message type that I described above.

If you don't, you'll lose `JointState` publishing (at least if you don't run another `robot_state` instance) and thus cannot use any of the ROS URDF infrastructure anymore.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-09**:
If you would be interested in option 1, I would be willing to provide my support. Please open a ticket over at [ros-industrial/abb](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/issues).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-09**:
Note also btw that the pose of the EEF is also available through TF, as the `tool0` frame. Requesting the transform between `base` and `tool0` should result in the same transform as the one the controller shows you on the TP. If not, that would be a bug, and a bug report would be appreciated.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-09**:
Perhaps also of interest is [PR12](https://github.com/ros-industrial/rep/pull/12) on the ROS-Industrial REP repository which intends to add a Cartesian extension (both state reporting as well as trajectory relay) to the `industrial_robot_client` packages.